# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I keep getting this "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." when trying to access my website, the error still exists without WordPress installed I tried reverting it back to a normal site and I kept getting this error

My hosting is from GoDaddy and the file manager is in Cpanel.

I have already tried uninstalling and re-installing WordPress.
Deleting possibly corrupt .htcaccess file.
changing file permissions inside of CPanel.

Comment: It might be a good idea to get in touch with GoDaddy's support team and ask them to look into this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The causes behind 403 error page

If the URL you’ve entered is correct, then it can be any of the following three reasons.

```
1) No index page
2) Empty html directory
3) Poor permission configuration or ownership issues.
```

The above listed are the most common reasons of 403 forbidden error.

You can contact Godaddy support as they will help you fix this problem.